# orderBy field not working with hibernate and mongoDB

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, grails-orm

I have a mongoDB set up that I access via GORM and I want to search for a param and then possibly orderBy another param. This works just fine for another search function I am using that is connected to a SQL table, but the mongoDB seems to be ignoring the order clause.

```
def itemList = Item.createCriteria()
def results = itemList.list (max: params.max, offset: params.offset) {
    if(params.searchField.equals("status")){
        eq("status", defaultStatus)
    } else if (!params.searchField.equals("id")) {
        ilike(params.searchField, params.searchString)
    }
    order('species', 'desc')
}
```

While I am getting my results to come back correctly, they are not being sorted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mongoDB *relational* table? Are you sure?

Comment: My apologies, the nomenclature is incorrect in the question. i will revise it. 

I am not using sql for this query, but GORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research I came across a simple way to sort the list using `sort{}` and `sort{}.reverse()`.

The actual answer looks like this:

```
results = results.sort{
    it."${params.sort}"
}

if (params.order == 'desc') {
    results = results.reverse()
}
```

Thanks for the help.